# How does Python achieve negative indexing in Lists and String

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

Just curious to know, how does Python in background achieve concept of negative indexing, because it is written in C, and as far as I know there is no negative indexing in C.

Comment: Post your code that you have used to scrape this field

Comment: Share HTML as text, not as image

Comment: @TarunLalwani added

Comment: @Andersson shared the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such situations I don't prefer using css. I rather use XPath for getting the text part. So here are possible solutions

```
'Description' : "\n".join(response.css('div[id = JobDescription] > span[id = TrackingJobBody] *::text').extract())
```

with xpath I would use

```
'Description' : "\n".join(response.css('div[id = JobDescription] > span[id = TrackingJobBody]').xpath(".//text()").extract())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tarun, I have one more question ,as you already have seen the page structure can you tell me the way how can I separate things like About the job, roles and responsibilities, qualifications etc (whichever is the heading) into different columns.
It would be appreciating if  you can help me with this.

Thanks